# solr puctuation issues

Tags: solr, schema, case, wildcard, punctuation

i have a field which contains

```
... ung eignen sich auch Computer-Rechtschreibprogramme.   Deutsch Erweiterte ...
```

i've configured it like this

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    splitOnNumerics="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />   
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[\p{Punct}]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

but

```
q=volltext:Rechtschreibprogramm*
q=volltext:*Rechtschreibprogramm*
```

give no results, why?

```
q=volltext:*echtschreibprogramm*
```

finds the document

i'm using solr 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed Solr 1.4 and indexed the data you asked. Problem is described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2438). Wildcard queries are case sensitive and they are not analyzed.That is why you did not find any result when you search with uppercase "R". It is solved on the Solr 3.6. You can send your wildcard queries with lowercase letters and it will return you the expected result.

Comment: hi i removed PatternReplaceFilterFactory but i'm facing the same issue, upgrading solr is not possible because i'm working with legacy code

Comment: You can use the admin/analysis.jsp page to see how your field analyzed and what causes the problem. I will install solr 1.4 and try it there.